# VBA Excel Save Copy as txt File

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, text-files

Is it possible to save a copy of a workbook as txt file?

I tried `ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs("wb.txt")`. However this saves the excel with txt without any file conversion. So when I open the text file no data is displayed.

Comment: [See this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/281422-visual-basic-applications-code-convert-excel-text-file.html)

Comment: or this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434994/export-each-sheet-to-a-separate-csv-file

Comment: You can't specify a format with SaveCopyAs. Copy the current sheet and use SaveAs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way

```
ThisFile = "Filename"
code.....
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\folderlocation\" & ThisFile & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim s As String
s = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
s = Replace(s, "xlsx", "txt")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=s, FileFormat:=xlCurrentPlatformText
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

This will silently save file in txt format and close original file.

Also you can find some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707851/export-excel-file-to-txt-format-via-excel-vba-gui).