# How to make excel automatically export a txt copy of my sheet each time I save my xlsx?

Tags: excel, vba

I use excel to edit tabular data and track the changes using version control. Each time I make a change in the xls(x) I have to go to File->Export, after which the excel continues to edit the exported file instead of the xls(x).

I would like excel to automatically export a text version of my sheet every time I save my xls(x) sheet, and continue editing the xls(x). How do I achieve this?

---

EDIT:

I saved the file as a macro-enabled file (xlsm), enabled macros and following John Coleman's suggestions, inserted the following code ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36479472/3516684)) into VBAProject->ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim s As String
    s = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    s = Replace(s, "xlsm", "txt")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=s, FileFormat:=xlText
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

but the active workbook becomes the txt file (and excel crashed immediately after). Is there a way to export and continue editing the original file?

Comment: Put the exporting code in the event handler `Workbook_BeforeSave()`

Comment: @JohnColeman I get the error mentioned above

Comment: In the `ThisWorkbook` module there should be a stub which you can call up: `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)` See this: https://www.exceldemy.com/how-to-enter-event-handler-vba-code/

Comment: @JohnColeman This seems to partially work: the active workbook becomes the txt file. Is there a way to export and continue editing the original file?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking -- saving doesn't close the workbook and you can still edit afterwards. Perhaps put `Cancel = True`  in the body of the event handler -- though you will have to find a way of bypassing the event handler if you go this route (or perhaps have a public Boolean flag which the event handler checks to determine if you really want to save).

Answer (score 1):

Save the file as a macro-enabled file (xlsm), enabled macros, go to Developer->Visual Basic and insert the following code into VBAProject->ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Application.ActiveSheet

    Dim s As String
    s = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    s = Replace(s, "xlsm", "txt")

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
    sh.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)

    wb.SaveAs Filename:=s, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
    wb.Close

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```